Can I choose RDBMS at runtime between SQLlite and mySQL in a Delphi 11 program?
I want the application to be able to run either locally (with SQLlite which does not require a server installation) or, if the user chooses at the beginning of the run, to connect to an Internet DB (using mySQL). It is not necessary to connect to both engines at the same time but it would not be bad.
Is this possible and if so how?

It is possible with mORMot

FireDAC allows connecting to both databases you mention. While most articles do show setting up FireDAC database connection at design time you can also set up the same connection at runtime.

You can do this in code.
Let's assume you have an TFDConnection component called FDConnection1 on your form/datamodule.
procedure DoDatabase(const AsMySQL: boolean);
begin
  FDConnection1.Close;
  if AsMySQL then
    begin
      FDConnection1.DriverName := 'MySQL';
      FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('Server=**put the name of the server here**');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('UserName=**put the MySQL user here**');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('Password=**put the password for that user here**');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=**put the name of the MySQL database here**');
    end
  else
   begin
      FDConnection1.DriverName := 'SQLite';
      FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('DriverID=SQLite');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('Database=**put the path to the SQLite databaase here**');
      FDConnection1.Params.Add('Name=**put the name of the SQLite database here**');
     // Optionally add any username and passwords here...
   end;
  try
    FDConnection1.Open;
    //// Uncomment the following lines if you want to debug it
    // var sMess: string;
    // if AsMySQL then sMess := 'MySQL' else sMess := 'SQLite';
    // ShowMessage('It worked, connected to ' + sMess);

    ... do things with the database here

  except
    // Something did not work... you need to fix it
    on E: Exception do ShowMessage('Exception: "' + E.Message + '"');
  end;
end;

A few caveats:

You might need to also use an external driver such as libmariadb.dll for the MySQL connection.
MySQL 8.3 onwards changed the way user names and passwords work so you may need to use the caching_sha2_password.dll and related items. They can be found here: https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/ - note that you need make sure your app and the connector shared the same 'bitness' (32 or 64bit).

I took this code from a little test app which worked correctly on my machine. Good luck!

I would not recommend to use mariadb components for connecting to mysql. These two database products forked about 15 years ago and discrepancies start to appear even at protocol level.
